# how to assign ip to shared folder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing

I have a file server on 2008r2 and I want to limit users to connect to the file server only from a given IP, for security reasons.

More information: every person has own shared folder on the file server that is assigned to him, and I want to limit the access so that each user can only connect from his office and only from the IP that is assigned to his computer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in functionality to do what you're looking for, specifically, in Windows Server 2008 R2 (or in any version of Windows Server, actually). The Server service, which handles file and printer sharing, doesn't have any capability to grant / deny permission based on client IP address. (This is something that Samba can do, but Windows has never had the capability.)

The closest you could get to this would be using firewall rules to limit access to the Server service, however firewall rules cannot be applied on a per-share basis.

Dynamic Access Control in Windows Server 2012 *can* use the client computer's identity (but not its IP address-- rather its domain Computer account) in permission decisions, but you're not working with that version of Windows Server so that functionality isn't available to you.

Comment: hi how about exchange2010 can i assignee an ip to a client

Comment: There's no functionality in any version of Exchange to restrict access based on client IP address.